# Connecting flight in the UK, Philippine Passport holder

Tags: visas

As I will be returning from Brazil, I passed thru Heathrow in London on April 13 4 pm and travel to Incheon by April 14, 12 nn. It is another less than 24 hours airside as I will not go sightseeing. Being a Philippine Passport holder, do I need a Visa for the UK then?

Comment: What is your destination, will you have checked bags, and do you have any additional documents such as a US green card? See [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/somewhere_else/yes).

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket/booking? Will you be actually staying airside? Note that some terminals close at night https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/london-heathrow-airport-guide.htm